# download generated images automatically multiple times

Tags: asp.net, image

I am trying to download around 1000 images. For that first I am generating random number, converting this text to image. After this on button click, I am downloading this generated image. This is working fine. Now I want to run this loop for 1000 times so that I can download thousand images. The below code works fine when the loop is running once,  but when the loop is running 1000 times, its not working as I am expecting.

Also, I want to change the destination folder where this images should be downloaded. How can I do that?

Below if I change value of variable i to 1000, the output is not what I am expecting

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                CallBUttonClick();
            }

```
    }


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var s = GenerateRandomCode();
        RandomImage ci = new RandomImage(s.ToString(), 300, 75);
        this.Response.Clear();
        this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=downloadedFile.JPG");
        ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ci.Dispose();

    }

    protected void CallBUttonClick()
    {
        Button1_Click(Button1, null);
    }

    private string GenerateRandomCode()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string s = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            int i = r.Next(3);
            int ch;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    ch = r.Next(0, 9);
                    s = s + ch.ToString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ch = r.Next(65, 90);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    ch = r.Next(97, 122);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
                default:
                    ch = r.Next(97, 122);
                    s = s + Convert.ToChar(ch).ToString();
                    break;
            }
            r.NextDouble();
            r.Next(100, 1999);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Adding RandomImage.cs class file

`using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing.Text;
using System;
public class RandomImage
{
    //Default Constructor 
    public RandomImage() { }
    //property
    public string Text
    {
        get { return this.text; }
    }
    public Bitmap Image
    {
        get { return this.image; }
    }
    public int Width
    {
        get { return this.width; }
    }
    public int Height
    {
        get { return this.height; }
    }
    //Private variable
    private string text;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Bitmap image;
    private Random random = new Random();
    //Methods declaration
    public RandomImage(string s, int width, int height)
    {
        this.text = s;
        this.SetDimensions(width, height);
        this.GenerateImage();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        this.Dispose(true);
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
            this.image.Dispose();
    }
    private void SetDimensions(int width, int height)
    {
        if (width <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("width", width,
                "Argument out of range, must be greater than zero.");
        if (height <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("height", height,
                "Argument out of range, must be greater than zero.");
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }
    private void GenerateImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 28);
        SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(this.text, font);
        bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, (int)stringSize.Width+30, (int)stringSize.Height+30);
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.DrawString(this.text, font, Brushes.White, 0, 0);
        font.Dispose();
        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Dispose();
        this.image = bmp;

    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to save you bitmap file on physcial folder. I have modified you code below:

```
private void GenerateImage()
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1, 1);

        Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        Font font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 28);
        SizeF stringSize = graphics.MeasureString(this.text, font);
        bmp = new Bitmap(bmp, (int)stringSize.Width + 30, (int)stringSize.Height + 30);
        graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        graphics.DrawString(this.text, font, Brushes.White, 0, 0);
        font.Dispose();
        graphics.Flush();
        graphics.Dispose();
        bmp.Save("C:\\" + this.text + ".jpg");
        this.image = bmp;


    }
```

I have also removed below code from button click and rested, it is working fine.

```
//this.Response.Clear();
        //this.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        //Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=downloadedFile.JPG");
        
        //ci.Image.Save(this.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        //ci.Dispose();
```

Comment: I had added the value 1000 only. Then u will get not the output what I am expecting. You can use the code in sample application to check

Comment: Its basically adding "downloadFile.jpeg,attachment", "downloadFile(1).jpeg,attachment" as the file name and I dnt want to edit rename filename for 1000 iamges which are being downloaded...so any way to correct the filename given to the images getting downloaded when i is greater than 1

Comment: Can u suggest any edit in my code itself to do the above work?

Comment: is RandomImage third Party tool?

Comment: No...a class file which I have written to generate the image.

Comment: Hi Manoj, I am not able to see the changes. May be bcoz of the format. Can u update just the code which is working? Too difficult to see the edited version.

Comment: I have added bmp.Save("C:\\" + this.text + ".jpg"); line in GenerateImage

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) works. If you use the Response object to serve a download, you can serve ONE file.

You are approaching the problem from the wrong side; you say "I am trying to download around 1000 images". That is a process on the client side, on the browser if you will.

Yet you are trying to solve this on the server side.

You want 1000 downloads, so you have to initiate 1000 downloads from the client, and let the server side, the one Page you're writing for that, live through that 1000 times.

In other words, you cannot "push download" multiple files from the server, you have to request them one by one.